# Сериализовать XML тег смешанного содержания

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

```
<e:Title Updated="No">Lower <e:Abbreviation Ref="ABBR-ATS" Updated="No"/> routes</e:Title>
```

XML файл на самом деле большой но проблема именно в этой строке. Код относящийся к этой части вот такой:

```
private ENR31Title[] titleField;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Title")]
public ENR31Title[] Title {
    get {
        return this.titleField;
    }
    set {
        this.titleField = value;
    }
}

public partial class ENR31Title {

private Abbreviation[] abbreviationField;

private string updatedField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Abbreviation")]
public Abbreviation[] Abbreviation {
    get {
        return this.abbreviationField;
    }
    set {
        this.abbreviationField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string Updated {
    get {
        return this.updatedField;
    }
    set {
        this.updatedField = value;
    }
}
}
```

Десериализую так:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ENR31));
resultingMessage = (ENR31)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader("enr1des.xml"));
```

Сериализация:

```
if (resultingMessage == null) { return; }

try
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(resultingMessage.GetType());
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, resultingMessage);
        stream.Position = 0;
        xmlDocument.Load(stream);
        xmlDocument.Save("createdFile.xml");
        stream.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Log exception here
}
```

Конечный вариант приведенной в начале XML строки:

```
<Title Updated="No">
    <Abbreviation Ref="ABBR-ATS" Updated="No" />
</Title>
```

**То есть отсутствует "Lower ... routes". У кого какие идеи как исправить это? Благодарю!**

Answer (score 2):

`XmlSerializer` не поддерживает смешанное содержимое.

Вы можете:

1. Использовать кастомную сериализацию ([`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx))
2. Вместо класса `ENR31Title` использовать `XElement`.

В обоих случаях придется вносить изменения в автогенерированный код.

Comment: я понимаю что придется вносить изменения. Просто примеров нигде не нашел.можете помочь?

Comment: @zirrama я их тоже что-то найти не смог...

Comment: Спасибо. Покопаюсь еще)

Comment: я добавил в класс _ENR31Title_  property _Value_ типа _string[]_.  Теперь все что нужно вставляет в XML но вот надо чтобы расположение запонимал. То есть вставляет вот так: `<Title Updated="No">Lower  routes<Abbreviation Ref="ABBR-ATS" Updated="No" /></Title>`

Comment: Попробуйте тогда вместо двух свойств указать `object[]`, с соответствующими атрибутами. Там, по-идее, должны строки с аннотациями оказаться вместе. Но я не уверен что XmlSerializer так умеет...